# bits/stdc++.h' file not found in Clion release on apple m1

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Before I deleted cmake-build-debug folder and relaunched CMAKE project following answer from the question: <>, everything worked perfectly.
I added this file to /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1, usr/local/include and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1.
The full error is

```
fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/d1.dir/e/1/d1.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/d1.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/d1.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [d1] Error 2
```

Comment: I believe this is good. You should never include that file. Instead use the proper `c++` headers from the standard library.

Comment: That's good. That include is bad to use.

Comment: Yes! Finally, a compiler error using `bits/stdc++.h`!

Comment: I run solutions to icpc tasks, which use this header.

Comment: You will have to convert the code you have from these icpc tasks to use the standard headers. This should not be too difficult and will help you if you ever plan to be employed as a programmer or software engineer.